# How to use Onitemclicklistner with GestureDetector in android?

Tags: android, events

i need double click event with value possition,
i'm using GestureDetector to detect doubletap, how can i get value possition?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any on item click listener.  You can detect by implementing onDoubleTap listener and onGestureListener.

Please follow http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/04/double-tap-event-using-gesture.html

Comment: thanks for your info but i need clicked value possition.suppose i've gridview & i show multiple images in gridview . when i doubletap on particular image i need image possition